# Just added second NVMe SSD - primary drive is still HDD - Optimizing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, performance, lenovo-laptop

I just purchased a new Lenovo E485 laptop that came with a primary 500 GB 7200 RPM HDD with Windows installed. I bought a NVMe SSD and installed it and everything works fine. Strangely, a SSD was not offered as an option for the primary drive when customizing the laptop from Lenovo.

What can I do to optimize the use of the SSD (short of reinstalling Windows on it)? My first thought was to move the swap file, however I don't expect to need it much since the machine has 16 GB of memory. Are there other tweaks to have Windows use the SSD for some tasks or generally speed things up?

I'm making sure to install all programs on the SSD when I have the option.

Comment: Do you have anything against just moving your OS and main programs over? There are several programs designed to make this a relatively pain-free process.

Comment: I don't -- what would you recommend?

Comment: [Acronis True Image](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/personal/true-image-features/data-migration/) would be my primary recommendation, but [EaseUS Todo Backup](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/migrate-windows-10-to-ssd.html) also works. Let me know if that answers your question.